# Looking for the current status of the Chinese national cryptographic algorithm design competition

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography

I'm trying to find the results of the Chinese national cryptographic algorithm design competition (which I believe is targeted towards postquantum algorithms); however I cannot find it.

I did find [this page](https://www.cacrnet.org.cn/site/content/854.html) which (from the title) appears to list the results; however the body of the text is in Chinese (and is an image, and hence Google translate can't do anything with it).

Could some kind soul either translate the text, or just summarize the results?  Thank you!

Comment: I saved the images, made a PDF, OCRed to simplified Chinese, and Google-translated. [Here](http://sudis.free.fr/China%20Cryptographic%20Society.pdf#page=3) it is.

Comment: Seems like the winners are Aigis-sig (i.e. improved Dilithium) and Aigis-enc / LAC.LWE (i.e. improved Kyber).

Comment: LAC.LWE is a separate scheme from Aigis-enc. LAC was in the 1st round in NIST PQC project, Aigis-enc is new.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The webpage you referenced shows the First-, Second-, and Third-Prize winners of the Chinese national cryptographic algorithm design competition, which was held in Chengdu on July 22, 23.  The goals were to support the construction of new network security systems and the 14th five-year plan of industry. The meeting hoped to promote a new era of industrial and technological development.  Because of Covid-19, the number of participants was limited to 200 (excluding those who joined online).

The First-Prize winners were:

[Aegis-enc](https://ietresearch.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1049/ise2.12009) and Aegis-sig

> Aigis-Enc is an encryption algorithm based on asymmetrical learning
> with errors (LWE). A thorough comparison between Aigis-Enc (with the
> recommended parameters) and a symmetrical LWE encryption scheme on the
> same scale (the sampling parameters are {η1, η2} = {2, 2} instead of
> {1, 4}) on Chosen-plaintext attack (CPA) security, computation
> complexity and decryption failure probability is made. In particular,
> the authors ascertain that the CPA security of Aigis-Enc is 160.895,
> and that of the symmetrical LWE encryption scheme on the same scale is
> 161.834.

Following a moderator's comment that is shown above, some information about [Kyber](https://pq-crystals.org/kyber/) and [Dilithium](https://pq-crystals.org/dilithium/index.shtml).

and [LAC.PKE](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/292.pdf)

> LAC is a package of cryptographic primitives whose security is based
> on the Ring-LWE problem. It contains a PKE and a KEM...